# Is it possible to write Phonegap Plugins for Windows, Bada and Symbian?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, symbian, phonegap-plugins, bada

Is it possible to write Phonegap Plugins for Windows 7, Bada and Symbian Platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link is to an article written a little while ago that can help you get started in creating a Windows Phone Phonegap plugin. [Plugins for PhoneGap + Windows Phone Mango](http://www.risingj.com/archives/92)